# Html2Canvas Extra Line Appears on image output (on Mozilla)

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, html2canvas

I am trying to convert a post written html, css to image format. However, I had an issue with a line that appears on the screen. I verified that it appears because of the linear gradient applied to a div layer. However, I can not figure out the reason behind it, making me unable to fix it. I'm going to share my html code and two images, the first one is html rendered by the browser, while the latter one is the output produced by html2canvas function.

Things I tried but did not work:

- made background transparent
- removed borders from gradient layers
- removed outlines from gradient layers
- add transparent borders to gradient layers
- added webkit and mozilla legacy gradients

I appreciate the help!

Note: I'm using ReactJS, and output format of images are.png

### **Rendered HTML On the Browser**

[image: Rendered HTML]

### **Output Image using html2canvas**

[image: Canvas]

As you can see, the line appears just when the applied gradient stops.

Here is the source code for HTML content of post and process of converting it to image using html2canvas.

HTML:

```
 <div className="post">
    <div id="post__img" style={{backgroundImage: 'url(?)'.replace('?', imgPath), backgroundPosition: focusX + 'px ' + focusY + 'px'}}></div>
    <div id="post__grad-up"></div>
    <div id="post__grad-down"></div>
    <WiMoonWaxingCrescent1 id="post__moon"/>
    <div id="post__text-up">duhanews.com</div>
    <div id="post__line-up"></div>
    <div id="post__text-title" style={{fontSize: fontSize + 'px'}}>
        {title}
    </div>
    <div id="post__text-down">DİJİTAL ULUSLARARASI HABER AĞI</div>
    <div id="post__line-down"></div>

    <div id="post__social">
        <img src={instagram} alt=" " />
        <SocialIcon network="twitter" bgColor="transparent" fgColor="#1DA1F2"/>
    </div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
.post {
    position: relative;
    width: 1080px;
    height: 1080px;
    font-family: var(--post-text);
}

#post__img {
    position: absolute;
    background-size: cover;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

#post__grad-up {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;

    background: linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1), rgba(0,0,0, 0));
    border: none;
    outline: none;
}

#post__grad-down {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;

    background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
    border: none;
    outline: none;
}

#post__moon {
    position: absolute;
    top: 35px;
    left: 10px;

    rotate: -120deg;
    color: #EBC815;
    font-size: 50px;
}

#post__text-up {
    position: absolute;
    top: 65px;
    left: 20px;

    width: 235px;
    font-size: 19px;
    letter-spacing: 0.15rem;
    font-weight: bold;
}

#post__line-up {
    position: absolute;
    top: 95px;
    left: 0;

    width: 198px;
    height: 1px;
    background-color: #fff;
}

#post__text-title {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 110px;
    right: 50px;
    left: 50px;
    text-align: center;

}

#post__text-down {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 35px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;

    font-size: 21px;
    letter-spacing: 0.11rem;
    text-transform: uppercase;

}

#post__line-down {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 75px;

    right: 267px;
    width: 546px;
    height: 1px;
    background-color: #fff;

}

#post__social {
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    padding: 16px;
}

#post__social img {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
}
```

Image Conversion:

```
 <button type='button' onClick={() => {
        html2canvas(document.querySelector(".post"), {scale: 1}).then(
            (canvas) => {
                var link = document.createElement("a");
                document.body.appendChild(link);
                link.download = "gönderi.jpg";
                link.href = canvas.toDataURL();
                link.target = '_blank';
                link.click();
            }
        )
    }}>Kaydet</button>
```

Comment: It looks like a sort of edge effect (when the system is trying to map one CSS (or part thereof) pixel to the several screen pixels that make up one CSS pixel on modern high def screens. Try zooming in and out to see if it changes at all.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know the technical reason but after switching to Chrome and Edge from Mozilla, the issue resolved, and the line did not appear. However, it persists on Mozilla. It must be associated with how Mozilla renders gradients.